# How to pass Parceable in an intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, null

I am having a problem receiving the extras that are coming in with my intent from a different activity. When I run the code and use break points at the line where the object is actually being created I can see it being created using the debugger. I can see the object being put in the putExtra() function.

Upon arrival at the resulting activity though using the function getParceableExtra() always returns null upon receiving the intent.

//In the receving activity

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(requestCode == 1){
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            Intent extras = getIntent();
            if(extras != null){
                Goals addToList = extras.getParcelableExtra(GOAL_PASSING);
                if(addToList != null)
                    mGoal.add(addToList);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

//In the sending activity

```
    incrementMGoal = (findViewById(R.id.create_goal_button));
    incrementMGoal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            Goals newGoal = new Goals(GT,GD,GDueDate);
            returnIntent.putExtra(MainActivity.GOAL_PASSING,newGoal);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

I expect when I create the intent to pass putExtra and then receive it to be put in a array. I am just receiving null however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is that your code takes the wrong intent and not of the `onActivityResult` parameter `data`

```
Goals addToList = data.getParcelableExtra(GOAL_PASSING);
```

so instead you should do this

```
Goals addToList = data.getParcelableExtra(GOAL_PASSING);
```

Comment: sorry, the first line was Goals addToList = extras.getParcelableExtra(GOAL_PASSING);